# matching occurrence of opposite number in a list python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list such has

```
results = [100, 100, -100, 100, -100, -100]
```

I would like to figure out the first occurrence of the opposite number. so first 100 would be match with the first -100, the second 100 would be match with the second -100.

I would like to have position as output such has:

```
[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5]
```

i.e : `[0,2]` represent the `results[0]` and  `results[2]`  where first occurrence of 100 is match with the first occurrence of -100

edit : you can assume there will always be the same amount of positive / negative and that the list will only contain 1 number

any help would be appricated

Comment: Say the input is `[2,2,3,-2,-3,-2]`. Does `3` match with the first `-3` (or is that already moved out of the window). Furthermore what to do if there is no such opposite?

Comment: you can assume there will always be the same amount of positive / negative and that it is always 1 number ( so no 2 and 3 occurrence, only 2)

Comment: and zero will not occur at all?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the fastest approach (for large inputs) should be the following one (though, my solution doesn't assume that the input list contains just one value and its opposite, so it can be made even faster if that assumption is added):

```
x = [100, 300, -300, 100, -100, -100]

from collections import defaultdict, deque

unmatched_positives = defaultdict(deque)

solution=[]
for i, val  in enumerate(x):
    if val > 0:
        unmatched_positives[val].append(i)
    else:
        solution.append( (unmatched_positives[-val].popleft(), i) )

print('Unsorted solution:', solution)
# If you need the result to be sorted
print('Sorted solution:', sorted(solution))
```

Output:

```
Unsorted solution: [(1, 2), (0, 4), (3, 5)]
Sorted solution: [(0, 4), (1, 2), (3, 5)]
```

Comment: indeed, very very quick , will have to do test on result*10000 to see fastest now...

Comment: its one of the fastest and most flexible one

Comment: @StevenG it only works if the first element is positive

Answer (score 3):

For your simple case where the list only contains 2 integers (`x` and `-x`), you could simply `zip()` together the indexes:

```
indexes = [[],[]]
for i,x in enumerate(results):
    indexes[0].append(i) if x > 0 else indexes[1].append(i)
list(zip(*indexes))
```

Example:

```
>>> results = [100, 100, -100, 100, -100, -100]
>>> indexes = [[],[]]
>>> for i,x in enumerate(results): indexes[0].append(i) if x > 0 else indexes[1].append(i)
... 
>>> list(zip(*indexes))
[(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)]
```

Note for small inputs 2 separate list comprehensions (e.g. `[i for i,x in enumerate(results) if x > 0]` may be faster than appending in a `for` loop.

Comment: very fast and elegant!  speed for result*1000 is 0.00200009346008

Comment: @StevenG thanks; on reflection it might be faster if you define `pos = abs(results[0]); neg = -pos` first and then use `==` instead of `>` or `<` while looping

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
results = [100, 100, -100, 100, -100, -100]

solution = []
for i, x in enumerate(results):
    if x > 0 and isinstance(x, int):
        y = results.index(-x)
        results[results.index(-x)] = 'found'
        solution.append([i,y])

print solution
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work as well for the general case in which different numbers occur:

```
solutions = []
for x in set(abs(x) for x in results):
    solutions += list(zip([i for i, x2 in enumerate(results) if x2 == x],
                          [i for i, x2 in enumerate(results) if x2 == x*-1]))
```

Comment: @StevenG: what is the size of `results` you test this with: if the list is small, that's not a good way to test things.

Comment: I did it on results*1000, and I get something like 0.626999855042 for zipa and 0.00200009346008 for Roelant solution

Answer (score 2):

Well we can do this efficiently in two phases. In the **analysis phase**, we filter out positive numbers, sort them and group them by index, like:

```
from itertools import groupby

subresult = dict(map(lambda x:(x[0],iter(tuple(x[1]))),
                     groupby(sorted(filter(lambda x:x[1] < 0,enumerate(results)),
                             key=lambda x:x[::-1]),lambda x:x[1])
            ))
```

Or we can generate it *step-by-step*, like:

```
subresult = filter(lambda x:x[1] < 0,enumerate(results)) # filter negative values
subresult = sorted(subresult,key=lambda x:x[::-1]) # sort them on value and then on index
subresult = groupby(subresult,lambda x:x[1]) # group them on the value
subresult = map(lambda x:(x[0],iter(tuple(x[1]))),subresult) # construct a sequence of tuples (value,list of indices)
subresult = dict(subresult) # make it a dictionary
```

This generates a dictionary:

```
{-100: <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fedfb523ef0>}
```

Next in **construction phase**, we iterate over all positive integers, and always take the next opposite one from the `subresult` dictionary. Like:

```
end_result = [[i,next(subresult[-v])[0]] for i,v in enumerate(results) if v > 0]
```

This generates:

```
>>> subresult = dict(map(lambda x:(x[0],iter(tuple(x[1]))),groupby(sorted(filter(lambda x:x[1] < 0,enumerate(results)),key=lambda x:x[::-1]),lambda x:x[1])))
>>> [[i,next(subresult[-v])[0]] for i,v in enumerate(results) if v > 0]
[[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5]]
```

Usually because of the dictionary lookup and because we use an iterator (that thus does bookkeeping on at which index we are), this will work quite efficiently.

Comment: nice approach and efficient, I get 0.0049 second with results*1000

Comment: @timgeb: I wrote it out multiple with multiple lines and comment on each one.

Answer (score 2):

How about this simple observation based approach? Split it into two lists using list comprehension and then just `zip` them in the order you want it.

**Using list comprehension**

```
In [18]: neg_list = [idx for idx, el in enumerate(results) if el < 0]
In [19]: pos_list = [idx for idx, el in enumerate(results) if el > 0]

In [20]: neg_list
Out[20]: [2, 4, 5]

In [21]: pos_list
Out[21]: [0, 1, 3]

In [22]: list(zip(pos_list, neg_list))
Out[22]: [(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)]
```

You can also modify what index you need from the order you `zip` them.

---

**NumPy Version:**
  For larger lists (or arrays equivalently), the numpy version should be much faster.

```
In [30]: res = np.array(results)
In [38]: pos_idx = np.where(res > 0)[0]
In [39]: pos_idx
Out[39]: array([0, 1, 3])

In [40]: neg_idx = np.where(res < 0)[0]
In [42]: neg_idx
Out[42]: array([2, 4, 5])

In [44]: list(zip(pos_idx, neg_idx))
Out[44]: [(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)]

# If you want to avoid using zip, then 
# just use np.vstack and transpose the result
In [59]: np.vstack((pos_idx, neg_idx)).T
Out[59]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [3, 5]])
```

---

P.S.: You could also use `generator comprehension` to achieve the same result but please note that it will be exhausted after you convert the generator to list once.

**Using generator comprehension**

```
In [24]: neg_gen = (idx for idx, el in enumerate(results) if el < 0)
In [25]: pos_gen = (idx for idx, el in enumerate(results) if el > 0)

In [27]: list(zip(pos_gen, neg_gen))
Out[27]: [(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)]

# on 2nd run, there won't be any element in the generator.
In [28]: list(zip(pos_gen, neg_gen))
Out[28]: []
```

Comment: very quick, on the best result with Leon and Chris_Rands

Comment: @StevenG Added numpy version as well. Please have a look

Comment: @StevenG : Added a complete `numpy` based solution. Please check it out!

Answer (score 1):

```
pos = {}
for i,item in enumerate(results ):
    if item < 0: continue 
    if item not in pos:
       pos[item] = []
    pos[item].append(i)

[ [pos[-item].pop(0), i] for i,item in enumerate(results ) if item < 0]  

[[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: thanks, works results*1000 speed is 0.00399994850159

Answer (score 1):

For the sample case where `results` only contains two different integers:

```
import numpy as np

results = np.array([100, 100, -100, 100, -100, -100])

output = list(zip(np.where(results > 0)[0], np.where(results < 0)[0]))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)]
```

Time is `~0.002` for `results * 1000`.